# Customize the standard outbound email from Salesforce

Tags: apex, email, apex-email-service

We have enabled EnhancedEmail in our org and our users are able to email the customers directly from Contact record as shown below

[image]

Since this sending of email from Salesforce to a contact is a standard out of the box functionality, is there any apex object available to customize it further ? (like how we can customize the inbound email via inboundemail object/apex email services)

UPDATE :

What we want is to insert an additional line at the end of the mail that display the user's title in the company. Is this possible ?

Comment: What do you mean customize it? Are you want to change the content without the user knowing? Perform additional logic on it, like a trigger?  Please edit your question to be clear on what kind of change you're trying to make to a sent email.

Comment: I have updated the post with the actual customization that we are looking for @Nick C

Comment: Did you try Lightning Email Templates with merge fields?

Comment: [email signatures](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000384376&type=1) ??